# multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$/$n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I apologize if this is a basic question, but I could not find the specifics in my book and online. I'm trying to work on multiplication on $\mathbb{Z}$/$n\mathbb{Z}$ and I hope I can get clarification on my understanding. Here's an example: (I'm going to deal with $\mathbb{Z}$/$12\mathbb{Z}$)
$$(2+12\mathbb{Z})(3+12\mathbb{Z}) = 3(2+12\mathbb{Z})+ 12\mathbb{Z}(2+12\mathbb{Z}) = 6 + 36\mathbb{Z} + 24\mathbb{Z} + 144\mathbb{Z}^2$$ And since $$36\mathbb{Z} + 24\mathbb{Z} + 144\mathbb{Z}^2 = 12\mathbb{Z}$$ Then $$(2+12\mathbb{Z})(3+12\mathbb{Z}) = 6 + 12\mathbb{Z}$$Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is usually defined simply as $(a+n\mathbb{Z})(b+n\mathbb{Z})=ab+n\mathbb{Z}$. It can be easily proved that this is well defined operation, i.e it doesn't depend on the chosen representatives $a$ and $b$. Note that this is in general **not** equivalent to what you did. For example, if we try your multiplication then:

$(2+4\mathbb{Z})(2+4\mathbb{Z})=4+8\mathbb{Z}+8\mathbb{Z}+16\mathbb{Z^2}=4+8\mathbb{Z}$

Which doesn't make much sense, as it's not an element of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. And even as a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ it is not equal to $4+4\mathbb{Z}=4\mathbb{Z}$, which is obtained by the usual multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

You are multiplying sets (specifically, cosets of $12\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb Z$) and you should not assume that the rules are identical with numerical rules.  In fact, the **definition** of coset multiplication is
$$(a+H)(b+H)=(ab)+H\ ,$$
so in this case
$$(2+12{\Bbb Z})(3+12{\Bbb Z})=6+12{\Bbb Z}\ ,$$
and there is nothing else you need to do.

Comment: Yes, the point is that "coset multiplication" is not quite "set multiplication" ... Not toooo far off, but, still, there is a (not-interesting) discrepancy. The "definition" of coset multiplication needs to be checked for well-definedness, in part, indeed, because it is _NOT_ just multiplication of sets. But, in the end, no surprises. :)